# Load sharedprefrence data to Textfield on page load flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a shared data that contain mobile no of customer,in my profile,that need to be filled with in textfield when i open profile page,i'm getting the data from shard preference data,when i load data to textfield it's throws error

```
TextEditingController mobile = TextEditingController();

  void initState() {

    getMobile();
  }
```

Get data From Sharedpreference

```
Future<String> getMobile() async {

        Future notificatinstatus = SharedPrefrence().getUserMobile();
        notificatinstatus.then((data) async {
          var mobile_no=data;

          mobile_no.text=mobile;
          return mobile;
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is better like this:

```dart
var mobileController = TextEditingController();

  getMobile() async {
    Future notificatinstatus = SharedPrefrence().getUserMobile();
    notificatinstatus.then((data) async {
      var mobile_no=data;
      setState(() {
        if(mobile_no.isNotEmpty){
          mobileController.text = mobile_no;
        }
      });
    });
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getMobile();
  }
```